# How to solve Schrödinger equations with potential $|x|^{2}$

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, schrodinger-operators

We consider  the initial value problem (IVP):

$i \frac{\partial}{\partial } u(x,t) \pm (\Delta \pm |x|^2) u(x,t)=0$
and

$u(x,0)= u_0(x)$, where $x,t \in \mathbb R, \Delta$ is the  Laplacian.

**My Question is**: How to  get  the formal solution $u(x,t)$ to the above  IVP? If we put $H= \Delta \pm |x|^2$, then what is $u(x,t)=e^{itH}u_0(x)$?

I am trying  to learn the basic about the above IVP. So can you suggest any references(papers/books)? I am also keen to see the what is the key difference in $e^{it\Delta}$ and $e^{itH}$.

---

**Background:** I am familiar with the usual Schrödinger equation:

Consider the linear Schrödinger equation,
$$ (LS)
\begin{cases}
\partial_{t}u= i\triangle u, t\in \mathbb R,\\
u(x,0)=u_{0}(x),
\end{cases}
$$
$x\in \mathbb R^{n}.$ Taking the Fourier transform with respect to the space variable $x$
in $(LS)$, we obtain,
$$
\begin{cases}
\widehat{\partial_{t}u}(\xi,t)=\partial_{t}\hat{u}(\xi,t)=\widehat{i\triangle}u(\xi,t)=-4\pi^{2}i|\xi|^{2}\hat{u}(\xi,t),\\
\hat{u}(\xi, 0)=\hat{u_{0}}(\xi).
\end{cases}
$$
The solution of this family of ordinary differential equations, with parameter $\xi,$ can be written as, $\hat{u}(\xi,t)= e^{-4\pi^{2}it|\xi|^{2}}\hat{u_{0}}(\xi);$ and then taking inverse Fourier transform, we have,
$$u(x,t)=(e^{-4\pi^{2} it|\xi|^{2}}\hat{u_{0}}(\xi) )^\vee= \frac{e^{i|\cdot|^2/4t}}{(4\pi i t)^{1/2}}\ast u_0(x):= e^{it\triangle}u_{0}(x).$$

Comment: Are you sure about the sign? That is, there is a huge difference between $\Delta+|x|^2$ and $\Delta-|x|^2$. The latter is well-understood (quantum harmonic oscillator).

Comment: @paulgarrett; Thanks:  Oh! I am not very sure about the sign.

Comment: @paulgarrett: I  have edit my question.

Comment: It is not possible to use TeX-style accents in text here, as the text is not process by it in any way. (It is only possible to use MathJax for mathematics, which has a similar syntax). Instead  formatting is achieved using HTML and you thus can use the HTML entity `&ouml;` This would not work in the title though. A feasible workaround is to copy-paste the rendered character from the post preview into the title..

Comment: this is a textbook problem, see for example section 4.4 of these lecture notes: http://www.ks.uiuc.edu/Services/Class/PHYS480/qm_PDF/chp4.pdf

Comment: The sign in front of $H$ is unimportant: you can absorb it in $i\partial_t$ by redefining $i$ to $-i$. The sign _within_ $H = \triangle \pm |x|^2$ is important. As Paul said, the case $\triangle - |x|^2$ is well understood as the quantum harmonic oscillator which is in practically every textbook on quantum mechanics.

Comment: The case $\triangle + |x|^2$ is known as the "(quantum) inverted harmonic oscillator", which is an oxymoron since there's nothing oscillatory about it. It is slightly less standard, and two places I know that treat the problem are http://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0703234.pdf and Section 7.5 of Muller-Kirsten's  text _Introduction to Quantum Mechanics: Schrodinger Equation and Path Integral_. Notice that since the potential energy is unbounded from below in a really bad way, the Hamiltonian does not control $L^2$.

Comment: In terms of you question about the difference between the propagators $\exp(it H)$ and $\exp(it\triangle)$: the difference is huge. You may benefit from looking at Hislop and Segal's "Introduction to Spectral Theory".

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mehler_kernel